# LINQ methods can be used to extract a single element from an List<string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

This is a `datatable` in C# ASPNET

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("p_int", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("p_uni", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0", "seat" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "X400" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4", "X400" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "X400" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "X4SVR" });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "X400" });
```

With the values of datatable I have compiled two different `List<string>`

```
    List<string> StringA = new List<string> { string.Join(", ", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("p_int")).Distinct()) };
    List<string> StringB = new List<string> { string.Join(", ", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => z.Field<string>("p_uni")).Distinct()) };
```

I need get the value `X4SVR` extract from `List<string> StringB` and tried

```
    var lb = StringB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("X4SVR"));
    Response.Write(lb.ToString() + "<br /><br />");

    var result = StringB.Where(x => x.Contains("X4SVR")).FirstOrDefault();
    Response.Write(result.ToString() + "<br /><br />");

    var content = StringB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("X4SVR")) ?? StringB.FirstOrDefault();
    Response.Write(content.ToString() + "<br /><br />");

    string ls_SearchVal = "X4SVR";
    var lobj_Result = StringB.All(o => o.Contains(ls_SearchVal));
    Response.Write(lobj_Result.ToString() + "<br /><br />");

    var value = StringB.Find(item => item.Contains("X4SVR")).ToString();
    Response.Write(value.ToString() + "<br /><br />");
```

the return's never only `X4SVR` value but are

```
seat, X400, X4SVR

seat, X400, X4SVR

seat, X400, X4SVR

True

seat, X400, X4SVR
```

How to do have this return with only value `X4SVR`?

Comment: You need to take a look at the contents of StringB. Your list has one item which is that string you are getting all the time. I don't know how exactly you want your list to be.

Comment: Try following :             DataRow row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("p_uni") == "X4SVR").FirstOrDefault();
            string p_int = (string)row["p_int"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not understandable why do you return the value you are querying already, but:

```
var value = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => z.Field<string>("p_uni")).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("X4SVR"));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I need return the value because do I have to compare with a value extracted from a database table. The return of your suggestion is correct, many thanks for this help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because both of your lists contain only one element (of joined strings).

Do not use `string.Join()` for this purpose. Instead, you want something like:

```
var StringA = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("p_int")).Distinct().ToList();
var StringB = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(z => z.Field<string>("p_uni")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Then, you can get your value using the following:

```
var lb = StringB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("someString"));
```